C++ Prefix trie wildcard matching
I'm trying to implement a url wildcard matching in prefix trie on C++.
For example:

url hello.world.com - (matches) world.com
h?llo.world.com - world.com
h?llo.w*rld.com - test.world.com, world.com
key.com - key.com
k??.com - key.com
k??.com - kss.com
*.k??.com - hello.key.com or hello.kss.com
So, asterix is meaning that everything before it doesn't affect on the matching. And the question mark doesn't affect only one character in specific place, i.e. k??.com doesn't match with ke.com
Asterix matching is already implemented, but the question mark one isn't. Could you, please, help me with it? The code is below:

#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

class Node {
    std::map<char, Node*> letters;

public:
    bool is_end;
    bool is_domain_mask;
    int value;
    size_t size;
    static const char question_mark = '?';
    static const char asterix = '*';

    Node() : is_end(false), value(0), is_domain_mask(false), size(0) {};

    Node* Set(char ch) {
        if (letters.find(ch) == letters.end()) {
            letters[ch] = new Node();
        }
        return letters[ch];
    };

    Node* Get(char ch, bool& is_question_mark) {
        if (letters.find(question_mark) == letters.end()) {
            
            return letters.find(ch) == letters.end() ? nullptr : letters[ch];
        }
        is_question_mark = true;
        return letters[question_mark];
        //return letters.find(ch) == letters.end() ? nullptr : letters[ch];
    };

    std::map<char, Node*> GetChildren() const {
        return letters;
    };
};

class Trie {
    Node* root;

public:
    Trie() {
        root = new Node();
    };

    void Insert(const std::string& key, const int value, bool is_domain_mask) {
        Node* node = root;
        size_t asterix_loc = key.find_first_of(Node::asterix);
        size_t question_mark_loc = key.find_first_of(Node::question_mark);
        std::string new_key = key;
        if (asterix_loc != std::string::npos && asterix_loc < question_mark_loc) {
            new_key = key.substr(0, asterix_loc);
        }

        for(char ch : new_key) {
            node = node->Set(ch);
        }
        node->is_end = true;
        node->is_domain_mask = is_domain_mask;
        node->value = value;
        node->size = new_key.size();
    };

    void IterateAsterix(std::set<Node*>& ret, Node* node) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return;
        }

        for (auto child : node->GetChildren()) {
            if (child.second != nullptr && child.second->is_end) {
                ret.insert(child.second);
            }
            node = child.second;
            IterateAsterix(ret, node);
        }
    };

    void IterateQuestionMark(std::set<Node*>& ret, Node* node) {
        if (node == nullptr) {
            return;
        }

        for (auto child : node->GetChildren()) {
            if (child.second != nullptr && child.second->is_end) {
                ret.insert(child.second);
            }
            node = child.second;
            IterateQuestionMark(ret, node);
        }
    };

     void StartsWith(const std::string& key, std::set<Node*>& nodes) {
        Node* node = root;
        for (char ch : key) {
            if (ch == '*') {
                IterateAsterix(nodes, node);
            }

            bool is_question_mark = false;
            node = node->Get(ch, is_question_mark);
            if (is_question_mark) {
                IterateQuestionMark(nodes, node);
            }

            if (node == nullptr) {
                return;
            }
            bool shorter_than_test_dom_domain_mask = node->is_domain_mask && node->size < key.size(); // handle domain masks
            if (node->is_end && (node->size >= key.size() || shorter_than_test_dom_domain_mask)) {
                nodes.insert(node);
            }
        }

        return;
    };

    std::set<Node*> Search(const std::string& key) {
        std::set<Node*> nodes;
        StartsWith(key, nodes);
        StartsWith(key + ".*", nodes);
        return nodes;
    };
};

#include "Trie.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// hello.key.com -> key.com, bye.hello.key.com, hello.key.com
// if asterix -> trim until last asterix: *.hello.*ey.com -> ey.com
// question mark -> ignore

int main() {
    Trie trie;
    std::map<std::string, int> urls = { {"moc.y??", 11}, {"moc.yek.olleh", 13},
        {"ur.olleh", 123}, {"ten.swen", 55}, {"ur.lleh.sw?n", 34}};

    for (auto u : urls) {
        trie.Insert(u.first, u.second, false);
    }

    urls["ur.lleh.swen.tset"] = 35;
    trie.Insert("ur.lleh.swen.tset", 35, true);
    trie.Insert("ur.lleh.swen.tset", 35, false);
    trie.Insert("ur.lleh.swen.tset.hello.???", 36, false);
    urls["ur.lleh"] = 21;
    trie.Insert("ur.lleh", 21, true);
    urls["ur.lleh.swen"] = 33;
    trie.Insert("ur.lleh.swen", 33, true);
    urls["moc.yek"] = 12;
    trie.Insert("moc.yek", 12, false);
    urls["ur.ll*h.s?en"] = 77;
    trie.Insert("ur.ll*h.s?en", 77, true);

    std::vector<std::string> test_domains = { "moc.yek", "moc.sek", "moc.yss", "ur.olleh", "ten.swen", "ur.ll", "ur.lleh.swen", "ur.lleh"};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < test_domains.size(); i++) {
        auto nodes = trie.Search(test_domains[i]);
        if (nodes.empty()) {
            std::cout << test_domains[i] << " --- \n";
        }

        for (auto node : nodes) {
            std::cout << test_domains[i] << " - " << node->value << '\n';
        }
    }
};

I've already tried to implement the question mark matching via IterateQuestionMark function, but it wasn't successful.
Expected results:

moc.yek - 11
moc.yek - 12
moc.yek - 13
moc.sek ---
moc.yss - 11
ur.olleh - 123
ten.swen - 55
ur.ll - 77
ur.lleh.swen - 77
ur.lleh.swen - 21
ur.lleh.swen - 33
ur.lleh.swen - 34
ur.lleh.swen - 35
ur.lleh.swen - 36
ur.lleh - 77
ur.lleh - 34
ur.lleh - 21
ur.lleh - 33
ur.lleh - 35
ur.lleh - 36


Might it not be easier to use a regex (e.g. convert your wildcard expression to a regex). You will have less debugging/development to do. Only optimize later if you have performance issues.

I would like to use regex, but it's slower than trie. And also i don't know how to optimize it. Could you give me a tip, please?

First try to develop some regexes using regex101 https://regex101.com/r/Ds9lHy/1 and then lookup the documentation for  std::regex::match. In general first make something that works... then optimize if needed. (Don't go straight for "fastest" code).  Don't forget to make your regex a static local variable so it is initialized only once at runtime (or find another way to instantiate it only once)

@AndreZ. -- Also, your trie class leaks memory.  -- I would like to use regex, but it's slower than trie -- What is faster, trying to figure out the error in your code and make your Trie class usable in a real environment, or spend maybe an hour using regex and getting a working program?  In the real world, time is money -- you can't spend time reinventing the wheel.  I know that a trie data structure has its uses (for example, auto-complete and incremental searches), but to have it replace what a regular expression does is (IMO) counterproductive.

std::regex has been part of std since C++11. But it's no gained enough attention, probably because nobody really expected to have it. See : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

@Red.Wave std::regex also seems to be quite slow compared to other languages.

@Unmitigated it's the chickhen and egg problem. You think that it wasn't used because it was slow. I argue that it's slow because id did not get enough attention that leads to improvements. The std::string implementation was a hard barrier for any further improvement on string manipulation libraries. For the case of OP it works. At this stage, redirecting him to 3rd libraries only creates confusion.
